# Align text vertically to middle not taking affect

Tags: css

I need to align text near an icon to middle.
See the admin word near the user icon in this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-morning-267l5

I have this css, but it's not taking affect:

```
.HeaderToolbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  fill: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I can not see 'admin' word or 'user' icon.

Comment: I can't see them either _ Perhaps you should include the relevant code here_ as suggested by @Paulie_D

Comment: Just use className other than `white` for component `UserAvatar24`. You will see it.You can style the `td` using `style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center"
                    }}`. But I would recommend you to use `div` with `flex box` instead of `table` for layout.

Comment: If I put the code you ask for environment  that it can be reproduced, and If I create such environment you ask for the code. The sandbox is up and updated and the problem is explained well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class to your  element and then add a css to your class:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
```

Comment: I took your changes to my sandbox and there it seems fine, but in my dev environment (a little bit different, the sandbox is not updated) still not :~, seems there is something that overriding it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use elements like `header`, `nav` and `div` for layout along with `flexbox` instead of going for `table` to layout your header.

Please check following code. It shows basic mark up for header component with navigation and logo.

```css
header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 54px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.logo {
  flex: 1;
}

nav {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ghost {
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <div class='header'>
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Logo</h2>
    </div>
     
    <nav>
      <button>Projects</button>
      <button>Projects</button>
      <button class='ghost'>Admin </button>
      <button>Profile</button>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </header>
```